# My Firebase query is not responding to childEventListener

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase Query is not responding to child event listener. Actually I am trying to compare phonenumber in my phone with the phone  number present in the Firebase database and I have Implemented Firebase query....which is not working as expected.
here is my code

```
private Firebase userLocationRef = new Firebase("https://XXXX-XXX.fiXXXXXo.cXX/users");

ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver(); //Activity/Application android.content.Context
        Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                if (Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                    Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
                    while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                        final String contactNumber = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        //All Mapping Stuff to be done here..
                        Log.e("Phone Number", contactNumber);


                        com.firebase.client.Query query = userLocationRef.orderByChild("phoneNumber").equalTo(contactNumber);


                        query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                                Log.e("Contact Found", "Got Value");
                                dataSource.createContact(contactNumber);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                                Log.e("Contact Found", "Got Value again");    
                                dataSource.createContact(contactNumber);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                Log.e("Contact Found", "Got Value again");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                                Log.e("Contact Found", "Got Value again");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                                Log.e("Contact Found", "Got Value again");
                            }
                        });
                        break;
                    }
                    pCur.close();
                }
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
```

and Last but not the Least here is my dataBase Tree in Firebase

```
Root
 + friends 
 - users
    - 9xx888xxx
         hasLoggedIn: false
         name:"XXXXXXXXXX"
         phoneNumber:"9xx888xxx"
       + timeStampJoinedaddclose
   + 989xxxx898
   + xxxx000000
```

Comment: Please Help Me It's Been a whole day....Thanx In Advance

Comment: What do you mean when you say the query is not working as expected? Do you get any calls to `onChildAdded()`? If not, does `onCancelled()` get called? Did you already run through the code in the debugger?

Comment: nothing happens....:-( no method get called

Comment: I found out that firebase server reply is pretty late....Plus in my query `userLocationRef.orderByChild("phoneNumber").equalTo(contactNumber);` if I remove equalTo() method it works with equalTo(contactNumber) it doesnt even go to onChildAdded() or onCancelled().   Actually I want to compare my data with data on firebase database....how would I achieve that??? As it seems this last option is not working :-(